# Is there a way to know if my UriI.Builder is making the right URL

Tags: android, uri, uribuilder

Not a problem just something i can't find anywhere
in my app I build a URL using Uri.Builder
All I want to know if there is a way to see the end result of the Uri.Builder
because there I do call information from several EditText boxes as well 
as spinners and I am unsure if it is actually giving the right URL

**Here is the URL builder, as you can see i am pulling info from 2 edittext boxes as well as a spinner populated by json**

```
Uri.Builder builder=new Uri.Builder();
        builder.scheme("https")
                .authority("www.smartpractice.co.za")
                .appendPath("files-upload-ruben.asp")
                .appendQueryParameter("MyForm", "Yes")
                .appendQueryParameter("ClientID", String.valueOf(R.id.clientid))
                .appendQueryParameter("Username", String.valueOf(R.id.emailtext))
                .appendQueryParameter("Pwd", String.valueOf(R.id.pwdtext))
        .appendQueryParameter("category", String.valueOf(R.id.spinner));
        myURL=builder.build().toString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `toString()` on the builder object:

```
 builder.toString();
```

Looks like you're already assigning the output to variable `myURL`, `builder.toString();` calls through to `builder.build().toString();` anyway, so either method will produce the same url.

Comment: And then i assign it to a textbox or something?? I am really new to coding(2 weeks now)

Comment: Correct. You can store it in a String variable and use it where you like.

Comment: Thanks mate, legendary, just a quick question how can i assign it i have tried now but i failed and I know the code is completely worng

Comment: If you want to set it to a TextView you would do: ```textView.setText(myURL);```

Comment: At the end i just used a toast to see the results, thank you